# Changes color of parts of 3D image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

I want to achieve same functionality of changing color of parts of image like https://www.owayo.ie/konfigurator_html/index.php.
I googled a lot and tried different methods [**like this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2d7ZN/).

this is HTML:

```
<p>Example shifting color Hue with .getImageData</p>
<p>(Original: left, Recolored: right)</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

With the help of information given at this link, I am able to change a specific color to other colors. Like, can change blue color in the whole image to other colors. Also, this method is very slow.
So main challenge is of finding different parts of an image and then applying color changes to that part only.

Any leads in this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using Blender and Babylonjs. Using Blender, we made 3D model and by using Babylon plugin in Blender it was exported to babylon.js file. Then importing babolon.js file in html and can change color of parts at particular index.